# Rails update creates a new object each time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Apologies in advance for a noob question/bad formatting. Its my first post. I will try to explain clearly. In my app I have two objects `quiz` and `quiz_question`.

I want to create a quiz that has 10 questions associated with it, but want to create them over 10 'pages' rather than one long form on one page. I am trying to update the quiz object but when the update method is calls, it adds all the questions again, so the number of objects increases rapidly 1, 3, 7 etc.

`quiz` has many `quiz questions`

this is my controller:

```
    def new
  @quiz = Quiz.new
  1.times{@quiz.quiz_questions.new}
end

def create
  # return render json:params
  @quiz = Quiz.new(quiz_params)
  respond_to do |format|
    if @quiz.save
      format.html{ redirect_to edit_quiz_path(@quiz.id)}
    else
      format.html{ render :new}
    end
  end
end

def edit
   # return render json:params
   @quiz = Quiz.find params[:id]
   1.times{@quiz.quiz_questions.new}
end

def update
  #return render json:params
  @quiz = Quiz.find params[:id]
  @quiz.update(quiz_params)
  respond_to do |format|
    if @quiz.save && @quiz.quiz_questions.count < 10
      format.html{ redirect_to edit_quiz_path(@quiz.id)}
    elsif @quiz.save && @quiz.quiz_questions.count > 10
      format.html{ redirect_to dashboard_teachers_path, notice: "Quiz Created Successfully"}
    else
      format.html{ render :edit}
    end
  end
end
```

And this is my edit view

```
   <%= simple_form_for(@quiz, :defaults => { :input_html => { :class => "hello" } }) do |f| %>
<%= f.error_notification %>

<%= f.simple_fields_for :quiz_questions do |builder| %>
<p><%= builder.input :question %></p>
<p><%= builder.input :correct_answer %></p>
<p><%= builder.input :incorrect_answer1 %></p>
<p><%= builder.input :incorrect_answer2 %></p>
<p><%= builder.input :incorrect_answer3 %></p>
<% end %>

<%= f.button :submit, class: "btn btn-default" %>
<% end %>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function () {
  $('input[type=text], textarea').each(function () {
      // Cache pointer to selected dom element.
      // Don't need to parse entire html each time you need that.
      var input = $(this);

      // .val() will return empty string if there is no value
      // 0 means false in this case don't need to use equality check
      if (!input.val()) {
        input.parent().css("display", "block");
      } else {
        input.parent().css("display", "none");
      }
    });

})
</script>
```

EDIT: For clarity. I want to advance through the edit action 10 times, each time adding a new `quiz_question` object and assigning it to the `quiz` object.

Comment: I think you are making `POST` call instead of `PUT` or `PATCH`.
POST will create a new record whereas PUT and PATCH will just update the existing record.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this didn't work. I think I didnt' clearly explain what I am trying to do. I added a clarifying edit which I hope helps.

Comment: I am not quite getting what you want to do, but if you only want to create questions, you cannot have a form for `@quiz`. Every time that one is submitted, it is going to create a new Quiz object.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to call the update action, you need to use `PUT`:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@quiz, :method => :put, :defaults => { :input_html => { :class => "hello" } }) do |f| %>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer,  but this didn't work. I think I didnt' clearly explain what I am trying to do. I added a clarifying edit which I hope helps.